# How to create a google TV emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, google-tv

I know this question has been asked quite a number of times before but none of those answers has been able to address my issue. I am starting development for Google TV. I want to know how can I create an emulator for Google TV so that I can Test the app just like other Android emulator for other devices. I am pretty new to this platform so please bear with me..:)

Answer (score 1):

Go to windows -> Android virtual device manager.Click create.

Then Create New AVD window will appear.

In that you have to choose the Android Tv Device as shown in this [link](http://postimg.org/image/tkc2mmi97/)

Comment: @ Naruto:  Thanks for quick reply...but I cannot find option for Android TV as it is in the link...DO I need to have Android 5.0 installed in sdk..because mine is just supported for kit kat??

Comment: @SouravSharma Go to Tools - > Andorid sdk .Then install all the api 19 especiallly android TV image